Databricks - add partition to the existing delta table
I have a delta table - table1. Files are stored in the azure delta lake.
It's an existing table and need to add the partition.
Is it possible to alter existing table or do I have to copy files and create a new one?

DEEP clone delta files
CREATE a new delta table with a partitioning

Thanks in advance

For unmanaged tables with data sitting in ADLS, you can try the following  to add partition columns on an existing Delta table:
You can try this approach:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE new1
(
  id INT,
  name STRING,
  age INT,
  DOB DATE
)
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (DOB)
LOCATION 'abfss://folder02@dileepstgacc.dfs.core.windows.net/01/new_tbl/';

Regarding the Deep Clone:
df = spark.read.format("delta").table("tbl1")
df.show()
spark.sql("""
    CREATE TABLE tbl1_clone DEEP CLONE tbl1
    LOCATION 'abfss://folder02@dileepstgacc.dfs.core.windows.net/cloned/';
""")
df_clone = spark.read.format("delta").table("tbl1_clone")
df_clone.show()

Results:
+----+----+-------------+
|col1|col2|partition_col|
+----+----+-------------+
|   1|   A|         NULL|
|   2|   B|         NULL|
+----+----+-------------+

+----+----+-------------+
|col1|col2|partition_col|
+----+----+-------------+
|   1|   A|         NULL|
|   2|   B|         NULL|
+----+----+-------------+

In the above code, reading the existing Delta table, perform the deep clone, and verify the cloned table.
